# Bulk Update Meta Tags?

Tags: meta-tags

I was wondering if it is possible to bulk update the meta tags for a particular content type? I have set the default to this: [node:field_description]. But all of the content is in the site. I'd prefer to not go through every node to paste that in the Meta tags Description field.

Is there a bulk operation to put that placeholder token into all the nodes of a particular content type?

Using this module: https://drupal.org/project/metatag The Metatag module on Drupal 7.

Comment: What meta tag module are you using? And what Drupal version?

Comment: Ah sorry! This one: https://drupal.org/project/metatag The Metatag module.

Comment: Hello. Please add important things directly to a question. This is not a discussion forum, comments may disappear without notice.

Answer (score 1):

You may use combination of Metatag, Views and Editable Fileds.

- Configure node types to use own fields for meta tags like
  keywords, description, abstract, etc. and create it. use Field
  Permission to restrict access to this fields.
- Configure Metatag to    use newly added fields for filling metatags
  on Metatag admin page    or node type page.
- Create view with table    display, add    metatag-fields. Choose
  formatter "Editable" on    each field    settings.
- Set path for this    view like admin/config/search/metatags/massedit. Save view and now you    can mass    edit
  any fields.

Also you can try Editable Views module.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there does not seem to be a way to bulk update the meta tags without some database or PHP work.

You're best bet would be to look at the structure in metatags table, and use PHP to join it with the node table on the type you want and manually update it using the database & serialize to put it back together. You may want to copy an already done serialized array from the database so you replicate the content.

But that may not be the best idea incase some have special parameters or something.